# Batch with Echo messages and then normal CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have a simple batch file:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO WELCOME
ECHO.
ECHO Launching your app...
```

What I would like is to return to a default CMD state where the user can type commands, I mean, this state: C:[path][path].....>
I want to give to the user the possibility to continue to type anything he wants after the echo "Launching your app..."
So visually it would give this:

WELCOME
Launching your app...
C:[path][path][path]> _

Comment: What's your problem ? if you start cmd.exe and launch your batch it will do exactly what you want ...

Comment: Or just add `cmd /k` to the end of your batch file. I do this for any batch file I want to see results from after double clicking to launch.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added cmd /k at the end of my batch as Matt said and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    rem check if started from own process (use our own parameter)
    rem and if not, spawn a new cmd with correct parameters and 
    rem keep it open

    if not "%~1"=="__startcmd__" (
        "%comspec%" /k "%~f0" __startcmd__ %* 
        exit
    )

    rem eliminate custom parameter of parameter list
    shift

    rem your custom screen
    cls
    title "command window"
    prompt $p$g
    echo WELCOME
    echo Launching your app ...
```